# Eliminating $\theta$ between the two expressions

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

How do we find the equation of this parametric curve $$2x=\cos {\theta}\left(\sqrt {\dfrac{3}{5}}\sin {\theta}+\cos {\theta}\right)$$ $$2y=\sin {\theta}\left(\sqrt {\dfrac{3}{5}}\sin {\theta}+\cos {\theta}\right)$$

I want to eleminate $\theta$ between the two equations and find $y$ in terms of $x$, but I don't see an obvious way to do this..

Wolfram alpha says this curve is a circle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On division, $\tan\theta=\dfrac yx$

We have 
$$2x=\sqrt{\frac35}\cos\theta\sin\theta+\cos^2\theta$$

Dividing by $\cos^2\theta=\dfrac1{1+\tan^2\theta},$  $$2x(1+\tan^2\theta)=\sqrt{\frac35}\tan\theta+1$$

Can you find the destination from here?

Comment: Yes..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
2\sqrt{\frac35}y-2x+1
&=\frac35\sin^2(\theta)-\cos^2(\theta)+1\\
&=\frac85\sin^2(\theta)\\
&=\frac85\frac{\tan^2(\theta)}{1+\tan^2(\theta)}\\
&=\frac85\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}
$$